# Delay subsequent ajax call until first ajax call is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some trouble with the timing of javascript events.  The problem I am having is that one part of the code seems to be executing before another part of the code completes.  I need to ensure that the first code finishes before the latter code begins.  Here is the initial code:

```
function(){     
    myLoop();  //this needs to complete before the call to myMethod below 
    $.ajax({
    url: sURL + "myController/myMethod",
    success: function() {       
    $.msg("My Success Message",{live:10000});
    error: function(){
    $.msg("My Error Message",{live:10000});
});
}
```

And here is the code that loops and inserts records into a db:

```
function myLoop(){
$('input[name=c_maybe].c_box').each(function(){
if( $(this).prop('checked') ){ 
    var rn = $(this).prop('value'); 
    $.ajax({
        url: sURL + 'myController/myInsert',
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {'rn': rn},
        success: function(data) {
            //not sure what to do on success.
        }
    });
} 
}); 
}
```

The problem that seems to be happening is that the call to `myController\myMethod` is happening before `myLoop` completes inserting all the records into the database.

Can someone suggest a way for me to redesign this code so that I can ensure that `myController\myMethod` is not called until `myLoop` has completely finished?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function myLoop() {
   var jqxhrs = [];
   if( $(this).prop('checked') ){ 
       var rn = $(this).prop('value'); 
       jqxhrs.push($.ajax({...
   }
   return jqxhrs;
}

function () {
   $.when.apply(undefined, myLoop()).done(function () {
      $.ajax({
         url: sURL + "myController/myMethod",
         ...
   });
}
```

`$.when.apply` is used to call `$.when` on the array of ajax requests, so `.done` is not called until they are *all* complete.

Comment: Very cool. I did not know about this feature of jQuery. I thought this was going to be an 'easy' callback question at first. Not so much.

Comment: Which feature are you talking about specifically?

Comment: `when` - I see it was added in jQuery 1.5. I look at a lot of jQuery questons on SO. I'm surprised I haven't run into it previously.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the $.when function that has been added to jQuery.

It goes something like this:

```
   $.when(ajaxFunction1(), ajaxFunction1()).done(function(response1, response2){
    // when the function calls are done this code here will be executed -> the response will be passed as parameters corresponding to the functions -> response1, response2
   });
```

Or you can try to use "beforeSend" within the ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(){    
     alert("doing stuff before the ajax call ...");    
   },
   success: function(){    
    alert("Whoa!");    
   }
 });
```

Comment: Your beforeSend solution looks cleaner than the other answers. +1

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  This has put me on the right path, but I am still having intermittent fails on my looping code.  I have posted another question about that.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) Feel free to accept the answer if you think it was what you needed :PPP

Answer (score -1):

You can make the ajax call synchronous. That way, the execution will be blocked till ajax call returns:

```
$.ajax({
    url: sURL + 'myController/myInsert',
    type:"POST",
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {'rn': rn},
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        //not sure what to do on success.
    }
});
```